# I am confused - I receive "getMonth is not a function"

Tags: javascript

even though i assigned a date to the variable, I receive the error message "getMonth is not a function"

Obviously the interpretor does not accept the type of date.

This is th relevant section of the code:

```
function init(){
            var m=document.getElementById("m");
            var d = Date();
            refresh(d);
        }


        function refresh(d) {
                var month = d.getMonth();
```

yes, the function is terminated by a } there are more lines to it, but it stops exactly there.

Comment: its `let d = new Date()`

Comment: Thank you very much. Even though I know how to instantiate an object, I just oversaw this. It's the little things, bothering the most.

Comment: no probs, happens to everyone

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to use new keyword with Date :

```js
function init(){
  var m=document.getElementById("m");
  var d = new Date();
  refresh(d);
}


function refresh(d) {
  var month = d.getMonth();
  console.log(month)

}

init()
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to get the constructor, while you're currently defining the function as `d`.

Read more about `Date` here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

So, the code fragment should be:

```js
function init(){
            var m=document.getElementById("m");
            var d = new Date();
            refresh(d);
        }


        function refresh(d) {
                var month = d.getMonth();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Date` is a class in javascript, so you need to use the `new` keyword to create a new instance and call methods like `getMonth` on it.

```js
function init(){
            var m=document.getElementById("m");
            var d = new Date();
            refresh(d);
        }


        function refresh(d) {
                var month = d.getMonth();
                console.log(month);
        }
        
        init();
```